# How replace last instance of space with comma

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a text file and I would like to replace the last space with a comma to facilitate data import and processing.

My text file has the following sample lines:

```
Some text 123 here and then 44.99
more text 789 is 33.75
```

The result I'd like to obtain:

```
Some text 123 here and then,44.99
more text 789 is,33.75
```

Comment: And did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex replacement:

```
Find what:    \h+(\S+)$
Replace with: ,\1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x4A7Mk/2).

**Details**

- `\h+` - 1 or more (`+`) repetitions of any horizontal whitespaces (`\h`)
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than whitespace (`\S`)
- `$` - end of a line.

The `,\1` replacement replaces the matched text with a comma and the contents of Group 1.

[image]

Comment: I need to know how I can replace the last "/" with nothing.

Comment: @HappyBird Could you clarify what you mean by *replace the last "/" with nothing*? `/(?!.*/)` -> empty string?

Comment: @HappyBird I see why you could not use `\h+(\S+)$`. Actually, regex S&R in a text editor may get tricky if you want to replace only on a single line. You may replace that pattern with `/([^/\r\n]*)$` and replace with `$1` or `\1`. The `\n` and `\r` are necessary to stay on the same line. If you use `/(?!.*/)`, you only need to make sure you do not enable *`.` matches newline* to stay on the same line.