# Replace last occurrence of space with sed

Tags: regex, bash

I need to replace the last occurrence of space in an input file, using `sed`.

What I came up with is

```
sed "s/([ ])[0-9]*$/,/g"
```

However, it does not seem to want to remember the space which it's supposed to replace. Running the command without round brackets works fine (for what it's supposed to do - replace the space *and* the chain of numbers). When I add the brackets, it does nothing.

Yes, I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616256/how-replace-last-instance-of-space-with-comma) solution, however when trying to pass `\1` to `sed`, it screams that "\1 not defined in the RE".

Anyone care to help? It seems to be a simple issue, I'd be glad to know the solution.

Comment: I presume you meant "the last space on *each* line"?  Or maybe "on *a* line?"  Probably not "the last space in the *file",* I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work "the first time" (yay) ...

```
$ sed -e 's/ \([^ ][^ ]*\)$/,\1/' /etc/hosts
```